# Response cache for Symfony REST API

Tags: json, rest, symfony, caching, fosrestbundle

I have a REST API using the FOSREST Bundle. The response is serialized by the JMS Bundle. Now I want to cache some of the responses because serialization takes quite some time. I was thinking of storing the response data after serialization and then, if database hasn't changed, deliver the cached response instead of doing serialization again. Any ideas how to achieve this?

To be more specific:
I have a Controller which outputs a lot of data which is unchanged most of the time. Since serialization takes a few seconds I want to speed up things
using the cached output.

I think I need to setup an event "afterSerialization" to write the cache.
But because fosrestBundle is configured to serialize all data handled by the view, I don't find a method to output pre serialized data without beeing sent to the serializer again.

```
public function postProductsAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    // TODO check if db is unchanged and cache exists
    // if check is true stop here and redirect to cached json response

    $products = $em->getRepository('PPApiBundle:Produkte')->findBy(array("status" => 1));

    $data = array(
      "data" => $products,
      "opt" => array()
    );

    $view = $this->view($data, 200);
    $ret = $this->handleView($view);

    // TODO cache json string after serialization 

    return $ret

}
```

Comment: How would you know that datbase hasn't changed?

Comment: in mysql it is possible to check UPDATE_TIME in the information_schema of the requested tables.

Answer (score -1):

You can use query cache and response cache methods of doctrine query builder to cache results before serialiation.

```
->getQuery()->useQueryCache(true)->useResultCache(true, 3600)
```

Comment: query cache is a good thing but in my case I want to cache the json output